# How to integrate Rasa Chatbot into website?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

> I have installed Rasa Core and NLU in my computer and after training
>   and build the models now my chatbot is ready but I'm not getting clear
>   documentation or way to deploy or integrate with a website.
>
> I have 'Rasa' named folder and 'venv' virtual environment. I tried to
>   put it into a website but they are blocking the files. So what is the
>   method to put the Rasa chatbot into the website for 24/7 live chat?

Comment: This link might be helpful:  [Rasa deployment](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/enterprise/deployment-environments/)

Comment: @Sociopath as a beginner I'm not getting those exactly, can you simply the way how it should fix the problem?

Comment: If you have core and nlu separate then you need to upgrade soon. After >= v1.0, core and NLU server have been merged.
Check this out on how to use rest APIs to create your own UI for your website: https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/connectors/your-own-website/#id2

Comment: @jainmiahshaik did you find a solution? there's no tutorial or good documentation for deployment on a live website using rasa-nlu

Answer (score 1):

For connecting your chatbot to a website, try using https://github.com/botfront/rasa-webchat i.e. "A chat widget to deploy virtual assistants made with Rasa or Botfront on any website." You'll need to add something like

```
socketio:
  user_message_evt: user_uttered
  bot_message_evt: bot_uttered
  session_persistence: true/false
```

to your `credentials.yml`. See https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/connectors/your-own-website/ for further details on connecting to your own website.

In terms of deployment, the recommended way to deploy a rasa chatbot is using Rasa X using either docker-compose or kubernetes/openshift. The easiest way would be to use the [one line deploy script](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/installation-and-setup/one-line-deploy-script/).

Answer (score 0):

https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/connectors/your-own-website/#id2
after training your bot run the command
rasa run --enable-api --cors "*"

Add the REST channel to your credentials.yml:

```
rest:
  # you don't need to provide anything here - this channel doesn't
  # require any credentials
```